Printing on a Pidion BIP 1300
Dose anybody have a .cab application that’s run on a BIP1300 that can alow me to print text from a input field?
My pidion uses wM 5.3.5.2 and the Microsoft .net version is CF 3.5 I don’t know if this information is important.
I search for a long  time and found an article on this platform for the bip 1300 and printing in C+
I have no experience in Programming ore something like that. I am a user :) but I like old hardware. My pinions laying around and it’s a shame. It’s the Swiss army nife  in POS Terminals.
What I expecting, if no software like this exist so pay for a programmer with this old skills vor an device form the past.
